# SQL Server Query for selecting rows with times based on a specified user-inputted timespan

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Is there a way to query a database to return rows containing data with a `time` datatype that is dependent on the user providing a time span (like for example, querying between 5:00 to 11:00 will return all rows containing times from 5:00 all the way to 11:00 and not simply exactly 5:00 and 11:00)?

Is the problem stated above possible? Or I should only rely on programatically setting the parameters in my program?

I know that this one will definitely not work with what I aim to know.

```
SELECT *   
FROM Consultation
WHERE (Consultation_Day = 'Monday') AND (Time_From = '5:00') OR (Time_From = '11:00')
ORDER BY Last_Name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition for Time is checking for exact time of either 5:00 or 11:00 for range you can do:

```
(Time_From >= '5:00') AND (Time_From <= '11:00')
```

So your query should be:

```
SELECT *   
FROM Consultation
WHERE (Consultation_Day = 'Monday') AND ((Time_From >= '5:00') AND (Time_From <= '11:00'))
ORDER BY Last_Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Or since you are using MS SQL Server you can use between

```
where Time_From BETWEEN '5:00' and '11:00'
```

So your query would be

```
SELECT *   
FROM Consultation
WHERE Consultation_Day = 'Monday' AND Time_From BETWEEN '5:00' AND '11:00'
ORDER BY Last_Name
```